# ion-slide-box with image not shown until the page resize

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I got a very strange problem. There is an ion-slide-box includes some images inside:

```
<ion-view >
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="false" >
      <ion-slide-box show-pager="true">
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="item in featured">
          <img class="featured-image" ng-src="{{item.thumbnail}}" alt="" />
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slide-box>
    </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

When the page is shown the first time, the slide box is empty although it seems to be correct in my browser's **inspector**. The images are appeared when I resize my browser although the data in my browser's **inspector** are the same. That means it has nothing to do with my data. What could be the reason?

By the way, my controller is like this:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

  MyController.$inject = ['$scope','$state','MySvc'];

  function MyController($scope, $state ,MySvc) {

    $scope.featured = [];

    loadFeatured();

    function loadFeatured() {

      MySvc.getFeatured(function(success, data) {
        if ( success ) {
          $scope.featured = data;
          //console.log($scope.featured);
        } else {
          alert(error.message);
        }
      });
    }
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing my controller code:

```
function loadFeatured() {

      MySvc.getFeatured(function(success, data) {
        if ( success ) {
          $scope.featured = data;
          setTimeout(function() {
                $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(0);
                $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
                $scope.$apply();
                });
        } else {
          alert(error.message);
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: You should use angularjs's timeout: `$timeout(function() {
                $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(0);
                $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
                });`

Comment: What's the difference between setTimeout and $timeout?

Comment: `$timeout` is already doing the `$scope.apply()`for you, so you do not have to called it explicitly. Google yourself for more information ;-)